# Maintain currently selected item in dropdownlist which is filled with jquery ajax after postback?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im using jquery ajax to fill the dropdownlist.Every thing works fine,but when i click the submit button(`a server side function will be called`), the dropdownlist is not maintaining the selected value .ie dropdown list will be loaded once again and the user doesn't know which item was selected before submitting the form.

What could be the problem ?

The code i've written is given below

```
$("#locationList").change(function () {
         FillCashSafe();
     }).change();

function FillCashSafe() {
     $("#CashSafeLists").empty();
     var locationNo = document.getElementById('<%=locationList.ClientID%>').value;               
     $.ajax({
         url: "HealthReport.aspx/GetCashsafes",
         data: '{Location: "' + locationNo+ '"}',
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data) {
             var optionhtml = '<option value="-1">Select One</option>';                     
             if (data) {                        
                 $("#CashSafeLists").append(optionhtml)
                 $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
                 $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                     $("#CashSafeLists").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CashsafeId).html(value.CashsafeSerialNo));
                     $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
                 });                         
             }
             else {                        
                 $("#CashSafeLists").append(optionhtml)
                 $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
             }                     
         },
         error: function (result) {                    
             $("#CashSafeLists").append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select one"));
             $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
         }
     });
```

The button click is as follows

```
<input type="submit" id="Submit1" name="btnSearch" value="Search"
class="btn btn-primary btn-Addbutton " style="margin-left: 4px;" runat="server"   
onserverclick="SearchButtonClicked"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no viewstate keeping the selected item of your dropdown-list so when your page posting back, ddl does not know which item was selected.

Comment: yes you are right.Any piece of code will be helpful.

Comment: set selected item inside the data return by ajax

Comment: Yest I understood your idea.but then how will i differentiate it between the other data returned by ajax